# Lost ETH sent from Bitstamp

Tags: transactions, ether, raw-transaction, pending-transactions, internal-transactions

I sent 3.99 eth to address 0x2cd41e1ba0bb66d3c05eaf8ee031e0c1f8866183

This address was provided by coinexchange.io. This is what I see from them now: "Internal Transactions Please note we do not support incoming 'internal transactions'. Please make sure the service you are using is using a regular transaction for all deposits to our system. We will not recover internal transactions."

I don't understand how you are an exchange and knowing this could happen would still execute as internal transaction. Did I just lose my eth?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a closed third party service/application https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/526/how-to-flag-3rd-party-support-questions

Comment: There's not much you can do. Keep complaining to their support, use social media to raise awarness of the problem. Sure their automated process cannot accept "internal transactions", but they can manually review your transaction and at least return or credit your ethers.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, it seems like they are telling you that you've lost it. That really sucks.

Are you sure it has not been credited to your account?

This is not Bitstamp's fault, it's coinexchange.io's fault. coinexchange.io has received the funds, just in a different way from what they are used to. Internal transactions are a unique feature of Ethereum. coinexchange.io knows very well that internal transactions can happen, or at least, they should know if they're working with Ethereum.

In my opinion, they should accept them. Internal transactions are not uncommon or unusual at all.

If I were you, I would send a sternly worded email or support ticket to coinexchange.io, telling them how much money it is, and requesting them to credit it to your account or return it to an address you provide. If they don't reply or tell you they can't do anything, I would escalate and send a certified letter with return receipt requested, and an email confirming the fact that you sent the letter, and the contents of the letter.

Maybe you should threaten legal action, although I don't know how much of a case you have.

If they don't cooperate, you should start complaining publicly on popular Ethereum and cryptocurrency forums, and maybe on Twitter. Try to spread some negative PR about them.

It is unacceptable that funds could be declared 'lost' in this manner, even though they have access to those same funds!

There is no technical reason why coinexchange.io can't credit it to your account and continue running their system as they normally would!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me. And I don't understand why someone down voted your response. But yeah I am totally with you on this one. I don't understand how this can happen. How can you just lose money in this manner. By the way, I left a ticket and they got back to me with a statement saying something about they will charge 10% to recover my funds as they have to manually do so. And that they don't give me a exact time frame to when since they many to get to. So this is clearly a way for them to make 10% from a lot of people. Not ethical at all.

Comment: @RicardoMorales, It could be an oversight, and just unwillingness to fix it. But it does seem shady to me.

Comment: Thats what I am thinking. And they have yet to fix it. Its just so disgusting for an exchange to act in this manner.

Comment: "threaten"? really?

Comment: @Infoholic yes :)